How to prove that ${\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^s+x}}dx}$ diverges for $s\leq4$?
This integral converges for $s>4$ because we are integrating over positive values and then
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^s+x}}dx
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^{s-1}+1}}dx\\
&\leq \int_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^{s-1}}}dx\\
&= \int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{s/2-1}}dx,
\end{align*}
which converges for $s/2-1>1$, i.e., $s>4$. Now, how do we prove that diverges for $s\leq4$?

$  x^s + x  \leq 2 x^s $

The second inequality should be a $\geq$ which proves the divergence

so $ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^s+x}}   \geq  \frac{x}{  \sqrt 2 ; \sqrt{x^s}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \cdot \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{s}{2}-1}} $

Of course, Will. Very nice :)

If $s\geq 1$ then the denominator behaves asymptotically as $\sqrt{x^s}=x^{s/2}$.
Therefore, the integral has the same character as $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^{s/2}}dx=\int_1^\infty x^{1-s/2}dx
$$
As $s\leq 4$, we have $s/2\leq 2$ and so $1-s/2\geq -1$. Thus, $$\int_1^\infty x^{1-s/2}dx\geq\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x}dx=+\infty$$
and the original integral diverges.
If $s<1$ the denominator behaves as $\sqrt{x}$, so the integral has the same character as $$\int_1^\infty \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int_1^\infty \sqrt{x}\,dx=+\infty$$
and, again, the original integral diverges.

When $s\le 0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & >\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+x}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_1^{\infty} \sqrt{x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^{\infty}= \infty
\end{aligned}
$$
When $0<s\le 4$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^s+x^s}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_1^{\infty} x^{1-\frac{s}{2}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{x^{2-\frac{s}{2}}}{2-\frac{s}{2}}\right]_1^{\infty} \\
& =\infty
\end{aligned}
$$
Conclusively, $I$ is divergent when $s\le 4$.
